# How to plot 3 axis info in a 2d plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is an example of a bigger data. Imagine this dataframe below and I would like to plot 3 information in a 2D plot, like a multiple lines scheme.

I would like to put the values of feat[0] to feat[3] in Y axis, number of features columns (4) in X axis and 'depth' values also in Y axis. Although I only managed to plot the information regarding just one row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'depth':[300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 306],
                   'feat[0]':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
                   'feat[1]':[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
                   'feat[2]':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
                   'feat[3]':[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]})

plt.plot(np.arange(1, df.shape[1]), df.iloc[0,1:])
plt.title('Depth 300')
plt.ylabel('Features values')
plt.xlabel('N of columns')
plt.show()
```

[image]

My idea is to plot one line for each row ('depth'). So the values would have a step based on the depth difference. So in the end I should get 4 lines like these:

[image]

Although I am lost with these plot positions. Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [parallel coodinates plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates.html) after offsetting your values according to depth:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'depth':[300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 306],
                   'feat[0]':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
                   'feat[1]':[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
                   'feat[2]':[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
                   'feat[3]':[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]})

offset = .01
offsets = np.linspace(0, offset*len(df), len(df), endpoint=False)
legend = [f'{d} (+{x})' if x > 0 else f'{d}' for d,x in zip(df.depth, offsets)]

pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates((df.iloc[:,1:]+offsets[None].T).assign(depth=legend), 'depth')
```

[image]
You may want to adjust the offset as needed.